# How do you say " can't wait to see you guys " in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase-request

How do you say " can't wait to see you guys " in German ?

Comment: I think your downvote refers to the guideline "If your question could be answered by a dictionary, a grammar book, or another general reference, consult these." See source [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Pollitzer: I don't think you'll find a GOOD answer to that in any dictionary, no matter how long you search.

Comment: @Pollitzer: The downvotes more likely are due to the lack of any research effort whatsoever.

Answer (score 4):

However, I would translate it with:

*Ich kann es nicht abwarten, euch zu sehen, Jungs!*

If you mean also women with "guys" it would be:

*Ich kann es nicht abwarten, euch zu sehen, Leute!*

Comment: Ich würde *kaum erwarten* statt *nicht abwarten*  einsetzen.

Comment: Stimmt, trifft es genauer, wobei meines aber auch nicht falsch ist.

Comment: Ich find' _kaum erwarten_ besser.

Comment: +1 for considering "guys" can also mean girls

Answer (score 2):

I would translate it like this:

> Ich kann es kaum erwarten bis ihr kommt.

if you absolutely want to have the "guys" in there:

> Jungs, ich kann es kaum erwarten bis ihr kommt.

Comment: That is only valid if the guys are visiting you, not if you are going to their place.

Comment: @Iris: True. In that case you'd write: Jungs, ich kann es kaum erwarten bis ich bei euch bin.

Comment: you'll get +1 if you update your answer :)